# CPTScatterPlotInterpolationCurved going out of bounds unable to determine scale

Tags: charts, core-plot, interpolation

I have determined somewhat flexible way to determine size of chart and axes, but I've got problem with CPTScatterPlotInterpolationCurved, because it can be higher than maximum data provided (unable to calculate how much easily).

Is there any property or method that can return maximum value after interpolation?

Example here (look at the top cut @ green tick)

[image]

Code that calculates bounds:

```
// Setup scatter plot space
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)self.graph.defaultPlotSpace;

CGFloat margin = [[self.dataArray valueForKeyPath:@"@max.floatValue"] integerValue]*0.10;

double xLow = 0.0f;
double yHigh = 0;
double yLow = 0;
double xHigh = [self drawnDataTilPlot:self.graph.allPlots.lastObject] + [self.dividedDataArray.lastObject count]-1;

if (round([[self.dataArray valueForKeyPath:@"@max.floatValue"] integerValue]/10)*10 < [[self.dataArray valueForKeyPath:@"@max.floatValue"] integerValue]) {
    yHigh = [[self.dataArray valueForKeyPath:@"@max.floatValue"] integerValue] + margin;
}
else {
    yHigh = round([[self.dataArray valueForKeyPath:@"@max.floatValue"] integerValue]/10)*10+margin;
}
if (self.type == GRChartTypeScatterLine) {
    yLow = [[self.dataArray valueForKeyPath:@"@min.floatValue"] integerValue];
    yLow -= margin*0.5;
    yHigh -= yLow;
}

plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xLow) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xHigh)];

if ([[self.dataArray valueForKeyPath:@"@max.integerValue"]integerValue]==0 &&
    [[self.dataArray valueForKeyPath:@"@min.integerValue"]integerValue]==0){
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(-1) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(2)];
}
else {
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yLow) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yHigh)];
}
```

Comment: ofc [_graph.defaultPlotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[_graph allPlots]]; doesn't work ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any way to do this right now. See the comments on [issue 131](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues/131) for one possible workaround.